# Using Unity New Input System issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am working on a project using Unitys new input system but I am having trouble getting my playercontroller script to work on mobile. I followed tutorials but I can only get the old system to work that is based on the free asset from Unity store.

My script is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ZombieInputAction playerActions;
    private InputAction movement;
    

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerActions = new ZombieInputAction();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        movement = playerActions.Player.Movement;
        movement.Enable();

        playerActions.Player.Jump.performed += DoJump;
        playerActions.Player.Jump.Enable();
    }

    private void DoJump(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
        Debug.Log("Jump");
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        movement.Disable();
        playerActions.Player.Jump.Disable();
    }

     private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            Debug.Log("Movement Values" + movement.ReadValue<Vector2>());
        }

}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Im a newby using the new system.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`! And what you should rather do is tag `unity3d` as this is the main framework/API you are using here